# Crop document photos with angled edge selection and post-processing the document like Magic Color in CamScanner app

Tags: images, image-processing, image-editor, png, jpg

I have taken photos of a few documents. I need to crop them, but the edges might not be perfectly rectangular or even trapezoidal. So, I need to crop the images with edges of arbitrary angles. And then, I need to convert the photos to look like documents. Both of these were possible with the CamScanner app (Magic Color for post-processing) for Android. Is there any software for Ubuntu that can do this?

My requirements are very similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1775615/851274), but my requirements are for Ubuntu.